# XSLT - Substitute code for string

Tags: xml, xslt, arcgis

I'm working on a XSLT inside a program and it uses XML 1.0. So, because it's inside a program i can't use other languages to do this. 
In the program i can select some options about my data but i'm not been able to get it from xslt. The code is now like this:

```
<!-- MD_DataIdentification.topicCategory-->
<div class="itemInfo">
       <span style="color: black; font-size: 13;">
       <span style="color: black; font-size: 15; font-weight:bold;">Categoria temática:<br /></span>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/metadata/dataIdInfo[1]/tpCat/TopicCatCd[(. != '001') and (. != '002') and (. != '003') and (. != '004') and (. != '005') and (. != '006') and (. != '007') and (. != '008') and (. != '009') and (. != '010')]">
            <xsl:for-each select="/metadata/dataIdInfo[1]/tpCat/TopicCatCd[(. != '001') and (. != '002') and (. != '003') and (. != '004') and (. != '005') and (. != '006') and (. != '007') and (. != '008') and (. != '009') and (. != '010')]">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="noContent">No information (mandatory)</span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </span>
</div>
```

The answer I get from the 'for-each' is a number of blank space as the itens I select. What i wanna do is associate the code with de information that it represents. Like 001 = farming, 002 = biologic, 003 = economic, and so on. Anyone can help me with this? How can i force the xslt to show the name of the code? 
I try to do this code but it doesnt work:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/metadata/dataIdInfo[1]/tpCat/TopicCatCd[(. != '001') and (. != '002') and (. != '003') and (. != '004') and (. != '005') and (. != '006') and (. != '007') and (. != '008') and (. != '009') and (. != '010')]">
        <xsl:if test="/metadata/dataIdInfo[1]/tpCat/TopicCatCd[(. != '001')]">
         Farming |
        </xsl:if>   
        <xsl:if test="/metadata/dataIdInfo[1]/tpCat/TopicCatCd[(. != '002')]">
         Biologic |
        </xsl:if>   
        <xsl:if test="/metadata/dataIdInfo[1]/tpCat/TopicCatCd[(. != '003')]">
        Boundaries |
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="/metadata/dataIdInfo[1]/tpCat/TopicCatCd[(. != '004')]">
        Atmospheric |
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="/metadata/dataIdInfo[1]/tpCat/TopicCatCd[(. != '005')]">
        Economy |
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
```

But when i use this i receive all the names not importing if it was select or not. 
If someone could help me I'll be very grateful. :)

---

I have another question too. In this < (. != '004') >, what the point is meaning? Thanks!

Comment: Can you include an example XML document? The point `.` in an XPath is an alias for the current node.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to answer your question because you did not provide any context or the expected output. In general, given an input like this:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <code>001</code>
    <code>002</code>
    <code>003</code>
    <code>004</code>
    <code>005</code>
</root>
```

and a stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <div>
        <xsl:for-each select="code">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". = '001'">farming</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = '002'">biologic</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = '003'">economic</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <span class="noContent">No information (mandatory)</span>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<div>farming, biologic, economic, <span class="noContent">No information (mandatory)</span>, <span class="noContent">No information (mandatory)</span></div>
```

Comment: Hi michael.horn257k, thanks for the help. I try here but i'm still have the same problem. I selected four options for text, and when i run the xslt i receive farming for all. I will update my question, check it. Thanks.

Comment: @EduardoPereira I cannot troubleshoot code that I cannot see.